# Remove Duplicate Nodes from SQL Server Hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchy

Looking at the below data is there an easy way to find IDs that exist at a higher level under the same leaf and remove them.

E.g. ID 4,5 exists in rows 4,5 , 8,9 and 12,13. 
i want to remove rows 4,5 as the same IDs exist further down the hierarchy (rows 8,9), but rows 12,13 stay as they are on a separate leaf.

[Rows to be Removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJAM0.png)

```
row ID  Path
1   1   /1/
2   2   /1/2/
3   3   /1/2/3/
4   4   /1/2/3/4/
5   5   /1/2/3/5/
6   6   /1/2/3/6/
7   7   /1/2/3/6/7/
8   4   /1/2/3/6/4/
9   5   /1/2/3/6/5/
10  8   /1/2/8/
11  7   /1/2/8/7/
12  4   /1/2/8/4/
13  5   /1/2/8/5/
```

Comment: 12 and 13 are on a separate leaf (do you mean branch?) how? 12 and 13 share a common ancestor with 8 and 9 (that is, they both derive from both /1/ and /1/2/). I'm not trying to be difficult; I'm trying to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

example for max ID len = 1

```
select *
--delete t1
    from table as t1
    where exists(
            select *
                from table as t2
                where left(t2.path, len(t1.path - 2)) = left(t1.path, len(t1.path - 2))
                    and charindex(right(t1.path, 2), t2.path, len(t1.path)) > 0
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach it should work for any length of ID:

```
with 
conversed as (
select substring(reverse(path),CHARINDEX('/',reverse(path),2), len(path)-CHARINDEX('/',reverse(path),2)) inverse_path, id, t.row
  from t)
select c.id, c.row keeper, c1.row deletethis  
  from conversed c join conversed c1 
    on c.id = c1.id 
   and c.row <> c1.row
   and c.inverse_path like '%' +c1.inverse_path;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id  keeper  deletethis
4   8       4
5   9       5
```